# Migrating C-->C++ Pointer to function throws compiler error

Tags: c++, c, pointers

TL:DR; I'm getting this error `error:   initializing argument 2 of 'int SocketSrv(int, int (*)(), int*, int, int, int)'` when compiling a project that used to be C as C++. The program compiled without warning (at that line anyway) as C code.

The code is:

```
rtn=SocketSrv(RxServConfig->port_nbr1, fn, &RxDataSocketId,
            RxServConfig->max_children,
            RxServConfig->shmemkey,
            RxServConfig->semkey);
```

The problem is that we give a pointer to a function `int function (int)` to a function that expects an `int function()`.

I don't even have an idea why this worked in C and I have no access to the code in the function that gets called.

Questions: Can I somehow cast `int (*)(int)` to `int (*)()` ? And again with the "why did this ever work ?" The function pointed to actually uses the parameter, does C pass along the parameter even though we declared a function pointer without parameters ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In c, `int (*)()` means a pointer to a function that returns `int` and takes a unspecified number of parameters, in c++ it means a function that returns an `int` and takes *0* parameters, so that's why it compiled in c but it doesn't in c++.

To solve this more information is needed, but you can simply write a overload for the function with the right signature and call the other from within it.

Comment: Interesting, definitely gives me a starting point for more research. It's in a block that calls a few different functions that are assigned to the function pointer, I'll have to figure out if they all have the same signature and then maybe write a wrapper. I guess it's not possible to have unspecified number of arguments in C++ ? Would changing it to a void pointer change things ?

Comment: @xyious you can try reinterpret_cast<int (*)()>(f) if you sure that the pointer passed has correct type and problem is in the declaration of called function

Comment: @xyious Perhaps it could work work with any of the two ideas you have, but remember to be careful and avoid *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It compiles with @Artemy Vysotsky's solution. Can the function that gets called (It's in a C library that gets statically linked) still call the function pointed to with a parameter ?

Comment: @xyious I think it's undefined behavior, you could ask a new question about it because I am not sure. First, make sure you search the web for an answer.

Comment: A function *must* be called with exactly the same amount and type of parameters. If you cast function pointers back and forth and at the end when you call it the prototype is respected, the C standard guarantees you that it works. If not, real life guarantees you that your code explodes.